Definition of contour maps in Hurwicz and Reiter (2006)
I was skimming through the introduction to Hurwicz and Reiter's Designing Economic Mechanisms (2006) and my attention was caught by what seems a definitional quirk to me. Let $\Psi$ be a space of functions, e.g. $F: X \to Y$ and $G: W \to Z$. Now define $\Phi$ to be a mapping that assigns each element of $\Psi$ to its contour map, i.e. for any $F \in \Psi$ let $\Phi(F) = X \setminus F$. Why would one define the contour map of a function in such a way?

The authors are defining the "contour map" to be a space in which there's one point for each 'contour' of $F$. If $F : X \to Y$...no, let's take a concrete example: $X$ is the plane, $Y$ is the real line. And $F$ is "altitude over some region of the earth", i.e., a function that tells you for each latitude and longitude in some region the altitude of that point.
A "contour map" (in ordinary ENglish) is the kind of thing hikers use:
.
If we consider each line in this picture, it corresponds to a set of points on the earth that are all at the same altitude, which we call a contour. One of the contours in that picture perhaps indicates an altitude of 240 feet. Let's call that one $C$.  For any point $P$ on a contour $C$, we have $F(P) = 240$. So if we define an equivalence relation on $X$ by saying that two points are equivalent if they have the same altitude, then all the points of $C$ are equivalent, and they form the equivalence class for altitude 240 feet.
So what is $X/F$? As a set, it has one element for each contour. But it also has a topology in which adjacent contours become nearby elements of the quotient. (I'm being very informal here, because I'm using metric rather than topological terms!)
Now if the target, $Y$, isn't just the reals, but something more complicated, like "(income, age, SES)" tuples, and X is "homeowners", then a contour is "all homeowners with the same income, age,a nd socio-economic status", which isn't so pretty and geometric, but it's still a set on which our function is constant.
And the idea is that if we consider the map $g : X \to X/F$ that associates to an item the contour that it lies on, then we can make a new function that associates to a contour the value of $F$ shared by all elements of that contour (which the authors call $\rho_F$) and see that $F(x) = \rho_F(g(x))$
for any $x \in X$. This is sometimes called (in topology, anyhow) "passing to the quotient".

Thank you. So $F$ here denotes both a function in $\Psi$ and an equivalence relation on $X$ defined by $x \sim y$ iff $F(x) = F(y)$, correct? The function $F$ itself is not an equivalence relation, in general. Confusing notation on their part.

Yes, that's right. I don't much like the notation either, but I think I've seen it before. It's certainly the sort of thing you can imagine thinking about, and then using $X/F$ as a shorthand, and then forgetting that others will be confused by this newly-invented notation,  because "it's so obvious to me!". :)
